# Burninate [bundle] and [bundles]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The tags [bundle](/questions/tagged/bundle) and [bundles](/questions/tagged/bundles) are currently a potpourri of unrelated questions, and have no clear definition as to what it means (and likely does not in general, as a "bundle" means drastically different things in different languages).

The description of [bundle](/questions/tagged/bundle) is as follows:

> A bundle is a directory that has a well-defined structure and can host
>   anything from classes to controllers and web resources. Even if
>   bundles are very flexible, you should follow some best practices if
>   you want to distribute them.

Clearly though, if you take a look at the questions tagged by both, most of the questions are not about this subject. I propose to burninate both tags (or, at the very least, treat [bundles](/questions/tagged/bundles) as a tag synonym of [bundle](/questions/tagged/bundle)).

Comment: [I just like to _say_ "bundle".](http://www.gocomics.com/printable/calvinandhobbes/1992/06/23/) Bundle bundle bundle.

Comment: Is there any possibility of clean up here? [tag:C#-bundle], [tag:python-bundle], [tag:cocoa-bundle], etc.? I think that would be preferable to just destroying the tag outright.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't looked at how the [bundle](/questions/tagged/bundle) tag is actually used in practice, but I would opposite its burnination because it has *at least one* very specific and appropriate meaning in the field of software development.

A "bundle" is a directory that encapsulates application- or framework-specific resources (such as executable files, supporting libraries, plug-ins, graphics, etc.) so that they appear to the user as a single file. These are ubiquitous in NeXTSTEP, OPENSTEP, and all of their descendants—OS X, iOS, etc.

I *suppose* you could do like Josh suggests and tag them [cocoa-bundle](/questions/tagged/cocoa-bundle), but that's not strictly accurate: bundles are a larger concept than the Cocoa framework. And you could concoct some other name, like [application-bundle](/questions/tagged/application-bundle), but [that's not what they're called in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html) or in common usage, making it hard for people to select the right tag.

And I don't even think it's necessary. We don't need complex tags like [c#-bundle](/questions/tagged/c%23-bundle). Questions can just use the separate [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [bundle](/questions/tagged/bundle) tags. That is, the *other* required tags on the question are sufficient to disambiguate which type of "bundle" is being referred to.

Comment: Well, [tag:cocoa-bundle] wasn't an exact, specific suggestion. I just meant, make hyphen tags for any major uses of "bundle".

Comment: @josh Problem is, that's an arbitrary name created specifically for the tagging system. Excise, in other words. In common vernacular, which is what our tagging system should strive to reflect, these things are called "bundles". If I'm asking a question about bundles, I want to tag it with "bundle". How do I know which one of those arbitrarily-named tags is right for me to choose? Why can't the *other* tags on the question determine all of the other required details?